Ubuntu 24.01 does not start - remmina.ssh-agent.service systemctl error
I had a problem with my Ubuntu Nvidia graphics and did a release-upgrade to update drivers. I am not sure if this release-upgrade also upgraded my Ubuntu to 24.04.01.
After rebooting, I cannot log on to the Desktop anymore. The error below appears to me.

Once I log on with CTRL+ALT+F2 in the tty, one more error will appear regarding virtualenvwrapper, as shown below.

The output of systemctl status of remmina can be seen below:

How can I log in again to the Ubuntu Desktop and get rid of these errors?

Your details are a little confusing; the release-upgrade will upgrade one release to another; so 24.04 will release-upgrade to 24.10, but you don't mention if you were using 24.04 before hand, or release-upgraded to 24.04 as you only mention one release. What were you using; as release-upgrade does not impact drivers as you said; but changes one release to a later release. Your question switches between updating drivers (ubuntu-drivers type commands) and performing a release-upgrade which changes apps/programs/packages so what did you do?

@guiverc indeed I am not sure if there was an upgrade of the Ubuntu release. I honestly do not remember the Ubuntu version I had before. You can see from my screen that ubuntu is 24.04.1. Errors happened after the release-upgrade and I am wondering if my NVidia-drivers have something about it (but I am not an expert on telling you so because errors are regarding remmina).
